# Google Calendar Widget Week View

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, app-widgets, google-calendar

How can I set the Google Calendar Widget to show the week view instead of the month view? I've browsed through all the calendar settings and just can't find any way to modify the widget's view. I can also add a "Mini-today" widget but that's not what I want. :)

My phone is Samsung Galaxy S5 Mini and the OS is Lollipop.

Kind Regards,
Tenttu

Comment: Look lik this is a problem since 2011, see: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/calendar/jal5PjrChzs Also, none of the workarounds mentioned on the linked forum worked for me on Lollipop. The official help page for this topic (https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/6110849?hl=en&ref_topic=3417921&co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&oco=1) does not mention that there's a way to set a default in the Android app. Looks like they simply forgot to implement that setting.

Comment: @AttilaCsipak Yep I have not found a solution for this problem either.